# limit amount of rows as result of groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My groupby code works fine:

```
df_20.groupby(['Jaar'])['GemeenteNaam'].value_counts()
```

It groups year 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018. How often a GemeenteNaam (in English: city name) is found in the column ['GemeenteNaam'] is given for every year with value_counts().

But this results in over 100 city's per year in my groupby result. I only want 10 city's per year.

**Question: how can I limit the rows as a result of the groupby?**

I tried this, but this of coure limits the total result:

```
df_20.groupby(['Jaar'])['GemeenteNaam'].value_counts().head(10)
```

I checked the groupby docstring, but couldn't find an answer. Hopefully you are smarter then I am (probably...). Thanks in advance!! greetings Jan (from rainy Netherlands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter values in lambda function:

```
df_20.groupby(['Jaar'])['GemeenteNaam'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(10))
```

Or add another `groupby` per `level=0` - by first level of index:

```
df_20.groupby(['Jaar'])['GemeenteNaam'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).head(10)
```

Comment: wow, you're fast! and good! thanks. This is exactly what I needed.. I know lambda and apply, but didn't think of using this for my question at all.. Thanks again, you helped me out!! greetings Jan

Answer (score 0):

Instead head(10) you can slice the first rows by:

head(10) ==> [:10]