# How to make a new pandas column that's the average of the last 3 values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a dataframe with 3 columns, `dt, unit, sold`. What I would like to know how to do is how to create a new column called say, `prior_3_avg`, that is as the name suggests, an average of `sold` by `unit` for the past three same-day-of-week as `dt`. E.g., for unit "1" on May 5th 2020, what's the average it sold on April 28th, 21st, and 14th, which are the last three thursdays?

Toy sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt':['2020-5-1','2020-5-2','2020-5-3','2020-5-4','2020-5-5','2020-5-6','2020-5-7','2020-5-8','2020-5-9','2020-5-10','2020-5-11','2020-5-12','2020-5-13','2020-5-14','2020-5-15','2020-5-16','2020-5-17','2020-5-18','2020-5-19','2020-5-20','2020-5-21','2020-5-22','2020-5-23','2020-5-24','2020-5-25','2020-5-26','2020-5-27','2020-5-28','2020-5-1','2020-5-2','2020-5-3','2020-5-4','2020-5-5','2020-5-6','2020-5-7','2020-5-8','2020-5-9','2020-5-10','2020-5-11','2020-5-12','2020-5-13','2020-5-14','2020-5-15','2020-5-16','2020-5-17','2020-5-18','2020-5-19','2020-5-20','2020-5-21','2020-5-22','2020-5-23','2020-5-24','2020-5-25','2020-5-26','2020-5-27','2020-5-28',],'unit':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],'sold':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]})

df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])

           dt  unit  sold 
0  2020-05-01     1     1
1  2020-05-02     1     2
2  2020-05-03     1     3
3  2020-05-04     1     4
4  2020-05-05     1     5
5  2020-05-06     1     6
...
```

How would I go about this? I've seen:
[Pandas new column from groupby averages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445009/pandas-new-column-from-groupby-averages)

That explains how to just do a group by on the columns. I figure I could do a "day of week" column, but then I still have the same problem of wanting to limit to the past 3 matching day of week values instead of just all of the results.

It could possibly have something to do with this, but this looks more like it's useful for one-off analysis than making a new column: [limit amount of rows as result of groupby Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209391/limit-amount-of-rows-as-result-of-groupby-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['dayofweek'] = df['dt'].dt.dayofweek
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['sold'][(df.index < x.name) & (df.dayofweek == x.dayofweek)].tail(3).sum(), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a new columns with the day

```
import pandas as pd
  
  
date = pd.date_range('2018-12-30', '2019-01-07',
                     freq='D').to_series()
date.dt.dayofweek
```

That will give you the number for the day and after you just need to filter with the month and sort the value

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea: First group by `unit`, then group each `unit` by weekdays and get the rolling average for `n` weeks (with `closed='left'`, the last `n` weeks *excluding the current one* are used for calculation, which seems to be what you want)...

```py
n = 3
result = (df.groupby('unit')
          .apply(lambda f: (f['sold']
                            .groupby(f.dt.dt.day_name())
                            .rolling(n, closed='left')
                            .mean()
                           )
                )
          )
```

...which results in this series:

```py
unit  dt           
1     Friday     0      NaN
                 7      NaN
                 14     NaN
                 21     8.0
      Monday     3      NaN
                 10     NaN
                 17     NaN
                 24    11.0
      ...
2     Friday     28     NaN
                 35     NaN
                 42     NaN
                 49     8.0
      Monday     31     NaN
                 38     NaN
                 45     NaN
                 52    11.0
      ...
Name: sold, dtype: float64
```

Next, get rid of the `unit` and `time` index levels, we don't need them.
Also, rename the series for easier `join`ing.

```py
result = result.reset_index(level=[0, 1], drop=True)
result = result.rename('prior_3_avg')
```

Back to the mothership...

```py
df2 = df.join(result)
```

Part of the final result in `df2`:

```py
         time  unit  sold  prior_3_avg
... # first 21 are NaN
21 2020-05-22     1    22          8.0
22 2020-05-23     1    23          9.0
23 2020-05-24     1    24         10.0
24 2020-05-25     1    25         11.0
25 2020-05-26     1    26         12.0
26 2020-05-27     1    27         13.0
27 2020-05-28     1    28         14.0
```